# IS it Possible to remove the left hand and top nav of SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

IS it Possible to remove the left hand and top nav of SharePoint Site.
My test page just like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the app bar, you could hide it with PowerShell.

```
Connect-SPOService "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"

Set-SPOTemporarilyDisableAppBar $true
```

But for the top nav, there is no native way to hide it.
You need to hide it with your custom CSS code and inject the CSS code into SharePoint using SharePoint Framework Extension.

It should be noted that subsequent updates of SharePoint may change the page structure and cause the CSS selector to fail.

A blog for your reference:[Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

You could download the SPFX app here:https://github.com/Haiqi-Wu/SharePoint-FrameWork-Demos/tree/master/react-application-injectjs-master

SharePoint Framework Documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview